# cannot borrow foo as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

I have following (innocent enough) Rust code:

```
let file = &Path(some_file_name);
let mut buf = [0u8, ..12];
match io::file_reader(file) {
    Ok(reader) => reader.read(buf, buf.len()),
    Err(msg) => println(msg)
}
```

The `rustc` complains that

> cannot borrow `buf[]` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

If changing the corresponding line to:

```
Ok(reader) => reader.read(buf, 12),
```

all will work just fine. But it is less satisfactory since now the length of the buffer is duplicated in the code. Although vaguely understanding why `rustc` complains, I still would like to argue that `rustc` should be able to infer that `len()` is a pure function and has no side effect so the code is valid. Besides, it is a quite common patten to read into a buffer that way.

So what is the idiomatic Rust way here?

**EDIT**: The code was for Rust 0.8. As @pnkfelix pointed out, the `Reader.read` API has been changed since then. It doesn't need the second parameter any more.

Comment: Care to provide your complete code?  I cobbled together something based on your code but I get a different error.  What version of rust are you using?

Comment: BTW, the `~Path` is allocating a box for the `Path`, when one could just put the Path straight on the stack and take a normal reference to it, e.g. `&Path`.

Comment: Andrew, the code was for rust 0.8. dbaupp, yes indeed. `&Path` would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is for my version of rustc:
rustc 0.9-pre (61443dc 2013-12-01)

1. The current version of the Reader trait has a different interface than the one you listed.  Instead of taking both (a slice of) an output buffer and a length, it now just takes (a slice of) an output buffer.  It can get the length of the output buffer from the slice, so you don't need to repeat yourself.
2. The reason Rust is complaining is that it is trying to ensure that you do not have read/write aliasing of memory.  It is trying to stop you from passing an immutable-borrow of `buf` into one context and a mutable-borrow of `buf` into another context.

   - When you say `len()` is a pure function, I take it you mean that it does not write to any mutable state.  However, in the general case, it could be *reading* mutable state.  (That is not the case here, since we are dealing with a fixed size buffer.  But still, in general one could imagine that we are dealing with some auto-resizing array abstraction.)
   - So there is an effect, just one that people do not often think about: that of reading.
   - I suspect the idiomatic way of dealing with the problem you saw (ignoring the fact that the API has changed) would be to avoid having the overlapping borrows of `buf`, e.g. like so:

     `Ok(reader) => { let l = buf.len(); reader.read(buf, l) },`

This way, you don't repeat yourself; you're just providing two non-overlapping extents where `buf` is borrowed in different ways.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks, pnkfelix.